# Porque mi bot no termina de ejecutar

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, gpt

Por favor ayúdame a entender porque mi bot no quiere terminar de ejecutar cuando doy "npm start " y se queda pegado

Estoy desarrollando un bot de WhatsApp que utiliza la biblioteca @bot-whatsapp/bot junto con el proveedor @bot-whatsapp/provider/baileys. El objetivo es que este bot interactúe con el modelo GPT de OpenAI para enviar y recibir mensajes. Sin embargo, después de configurar todo y escanear el código QR, mi aplicación no avanza ni ejecuta ninguna otra acción; simplemente se queda esperando.

**chatgpt.class.js**

```
class ChatGPTClass {
    queue = [];
    optionsGPT = { model: "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301" };
    openai = undefined;

    constructor() {
        console.log("Iniciando constructor de ChatGPTClass...");
        this.init().then(() => {
            console.log("Constructor de ChatGPTClass finalizado.");
        });
    }

    /**
     * Esta función inicializa
     */
    init = async () => {
        console.log("Iniciando función init...");
        const { ChatGPTAPI } = await import("chatgpt");
        this.openai = new ChatGPTAPI({
            apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY
        });
        console.log("Función init completada.");
    };

    /**
     * Manejador de los mensajes
     * su función es enviar un mensaje a WhatsApp
     * @param {*} ctx 
     */
    handleMsgChatGPT = async (body) => {
        console.log("Manejando mensaje de ChatGPT...");
        const interaccionChatGPT = await this.openai.sendMessage(body, {
            conversationId: !this.queue.length
                ? undefined
                : this.queue[this.queue.length - 1].conversationId,
            parentMessageId: !this.queue.length
                ? undefined
                : this.queue[this.queue.length - 1].id,
        });

        this.queue.push(interaccionChatGPT);
        console.log("Mensaje manejado y añadido a la cola.");
        return interaccionChatGPT;
    };
}

module.exports = ChatGPTClass;
```

Desde que agregue chat GPT en bot no quiere terminar de ejecutarse y se queda atascado, qué tengo mal en mi código?  puse un error log para ver donde se detiene pero no sale error, simplemente no termina de ejecutar, estoy usando el paquete https://bot-whatsapp.netlify.app/docs/

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

app.js

````
const axios = require("axios");
const { 
    createBot,
    createProvider,
    createFlow,
    addKeyword,
    addAnswer,
} = require('@bot-whatsapp/bot');

const QRPortalWeb = require('@bot-whatsapp/portal');
const BaileysProvider = require('@bot-whatsapp/provider/baileys');
const MockAdapter = require('@bot-whatsapp/database/mock');
const ChatGPTClass = require('./chatgpt.class');
const {PROMP} = require("./promp");

console.log("Importaciones completadas.");

/**(2) FLUJO DEL CHAT BOT */
const ChatGPTInstance = new ChatGPTClass();

const flowConfirmar = addKeyword(['1','2','3']).addAnswer('Excelente eleccion!');

const flowInicial = addKeyword("Hola")
.addAnswer("buenas!", null, async() => {
    console.log("Ejecutando flujo de respuesta 'buenas!'.");
    await ChatGPTInstance.handleMsgChatGPT(PROMP);
})
.addAnswer(
     "Bienvenido a nuestro proyecto ¿Qué quieres saber?",
    { capture: true},
    async (ctx, { flowDinamic, fallBack}) => {
        console.log("Ejecutando flujo de respuesta '¿Qué quieres saber?'.");
        const response = await ChatGPTInstance.handleMsgChatGPT(promp);
        const message = response.text; //respuestas
        if(ctx.body.toString() !== ['1','2','3']){
            await fallBack(message);
        }
    },[flowConfirmar]
);

console.log("Flujos de chat configurados.");

const createBotChatGPT = async({provider, database}) => {
    console.log("Creando instancia de ChatGPT...");
    return new ChatGPTClass(database, provider);
}

/** (3) SECCION PRINCIPAL DEL SCRIPT */
const main = async () => {
    console.log("Iniciando función principal...");

    const adapterDB = new MockAdapter();
    const adapterFlow = createFlow([flowInicial]);
    const adapterProvider = createProvider(BaileysProvider);

    createBotChatGPT({
        flow: adapterFlow,
        provider: adapterProvider,
        database: adapterDB,
    });

    QRPortalWeb();

    console.log("Función principal completada.");
}

console.log("Ejecutando función principal...");
main(); ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFr3X.png
````

Answer (score 0):

Intenta utilizar la libreria de openai.
Deberias cambiar
await import("chatgpt");
por:
await import("openai");

verificar doc:https://platform.openai.com/docs/libraries/node-js-library

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).